# What Java libraries does Batoo depend on, such as com.google.common.collect.Maps?

Tags: jpa, batoo

Stack overflow is the only avenue for getting any information on how to use Batoo, as there is little to no documentation on how to get it integrated into a Java application.

My very simple and germane question is, what are the Java library dependencies for using Batoo?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a request for writing documentation

Comment: If there is no documentation for software, and you don't want to look at the code and work it out, then why would you use it when there are ample other implementations of JPA?

Comment: Because Batoo claims to be 10 to 20 times faster than any other implementation, and it seems worthwhile to see if this is true.

Comment: lol. good luck with that

Answer (score 2):

The dependencies are listed in the [pom.xml file](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.batoo.jpa%7Cbatoo-jpa%7C2.0.1.2%7Cbundle), as for any other library deployed in a Maven repository. That said, I would never use a product that claims to be the fastest but doesn't provide any documentation, except the way to write the persistance.xml (sic!) file.